# Laplace's Method to verify an asymptotic approximation

Tags: asymptotics

Question:
Using Laplace’s method, verify the following asymptotic approximations as $x \to \infty$

$$\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t} \ln t \, dt \sim \left(\frac{2\pi}{x}\right)^{1/2} e^{-x}$$

I am struggling to get this equation into the form of

$$\int_\alpha^\beta g(t)e^{xh(t)} \, dt$$

Comment: as an alternative or double check, you may note that the integral above is given by $\partial_x \Gamma(x+1)$. Now apply Stirling.

Comment: @tired differentiating an asyptotic approximation is risky business; there's no guarantee in general that it will give you the asymptotic of the derivative. Is there some property here that makes it so?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas, you are right, but if i remember correctly the stirling expansion fits into the requirements for differentiating asymptotic expansions given in "Asymptotics and Special Functions" by Olver. I try to read it up later...but i think it is related to the fact the Gamma function is analytic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed asymptotic is very wrong. Where did it come from?

As a rule of thumb, if there is another exponential factor in the integral then it will somehow be involved in the desired $e^{xh(t)}$ factor. Your integral is

$$
\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\ln t\,dt = \int_0^\infty e^{x\ln t} e^{-t}\ln t\,dt = \int_0^\infty \exp(x\ln t - t)\ln t\,dt.
$$

Now we need to balance $x\ln t$ with $-t$, and substituting $t=xs$ does so:

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \exp(x\ln t - t)\ln t\,dt \\
&\qquad= x\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[ x\ln(xs) - xs \Bigr] \ln (xs)\,ds \\
&\qquad= x^{x+1} \int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[ x(\ln s - s) \Bigr] \ln (xs)\,ds \\
&\qquad= x^{x+1}\ln x \int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[ x(\ln s - s) \Bigr]\,ds + x^{x+1} \int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[ x(\ln s - s) \Bigr] \ln s\,ds \\
&\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
$$

The zero of $\ln s$ at the critical point $s=1$ in the second integral makes it asymptotically smaller than the first integral.  By the Laplace method we therefore have

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[ x(\ln s - s) \Bigr]\,ds \sim e^{-x} x^{-1/2}  \sqrt{2\pi}, \\
&\int_0^\infty \exp\Bigl[ x(\ln s - s) \Bigr] \ln s\,ds = o(x^{-1/2}).
\end{align}
$$

Thus, substituting the first into $(*)$ gives

> $$
> \int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\ln t\,dt \sim \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x \sqrt{2\pi x} \ln x, \qquad x \to \infty.
> $$

Here's a plot of

$$
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(x/e)^x\sqrt{x}} \int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\ln t\,dt}
$$

in blue versus

$$
\color{red}{\sqrt{2\pi} \ln x}
$$

in red:

[image]

Comment: Completely correct, the proposed asymptotic has been written wrong and your answer is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $t = e^{\ln t}$ and hence $t^x = e^{x\ln t}$, we have:
$$
\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t} \ln t \, dt = \int_0^\infty \underbrace{e^{-t} \ln t}_{g(t)} \  e^{x\ln t} \, dt
$$